# Shortcut to Apply the "number format" with two decimal places (negative numbers appear in red with parentheses)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Is there any shortcut to Apply the "number format" with two decimal places (negative numbers appear in red with parentheses). I am aware of Ctrl + Shift + $ but this gives the number in currency format and not number format.
I am also aware of CONTROL + SHIFT + % but this does not give the number in red with parentheses.

Comment: Record a macro, or copy/paste cell format?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such shortcut listed on the [Excel Shortcut and Function Keys](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-shortcut-and-function-keys-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f)

> NOTE   If an action that you use often does not have a shortcut key, you can record a macro to create one.

You have a few options:

1. Copy/Paste Cell format
2. Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> hotkey with a range of cells to bring up the Cell Formatting dialog and apply manually to the selected range
3. Record a macro and assign your own hotkey (suggested by Microsoft at the link above)
4. Apply the formatting manually to a single cell, then select a range of cells and press <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: Thanks David. I am aware of this but I wanted to know the excel short cut key (if any) for this.

Comment: I've given you two shortcut keys that will *assist* with this specific problem, as well as the link to complete list of shortcut/hotkeys from Microsoft. Does this answer the question? (If so, please consider marking it as "Accepted")

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd>